# Calculate Distance b/w Two Point in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I have have done map representation on Netlogo Using GIS Extension and loaded the data using .shp dataset. Now I want to get distance b.w two points. [image: check image]

Is there any way to get the distance b.w two stations which I represented in blue color. The distance needs to be calculated by the roads (eg. red and white lines)

```
extensions [GIS]

globals [
  boundaries-gis1
Roads-gis2
  Fire_Stations-gis3
waypoints
    Buildings-gis4
]


to load

clear-all


  set Boundaries-gis1 gis:load-dataset "Boundaries.shp"
  set Roads-gis2 gis:load-dataset "Roads.shp"
  set Fire_Stations-gis3 gis:load-dataset "Fire_Stations.shp"
  set Buildings-gis4 gis:load-dataset "Buildings.shp"

  gis:set-world-envelope (gis:envelope-union-of (gis:envelope-of Boundaries-gis1)
                                                (gis:envelope-of Roads-gis2)
                                                 (gis:envelope-of Fire_Stations-gis3)
                                                 (gis:envelope-of Buildings-gis4)
                                                )


  gis:set-drawing-color red
  gis:draw Boundaries-gis1 2

  gis:set-drawing-color white
  gis:draw Roads-gis2 1

  gis:set-drawing-color blue
  gis:draw Fire_Stations-gis3 5

  gis:set-drawing-color pink
  gis:draw Buildings-gis4 2







  end
```

Comment: General approach is to create agents (maybe called nodes) at intersections of roads and significant bands, and create links between the nodes for the roads. Then you can calculate distances along the network using the network extension paths and distances primitives.

Comment: Any Example or reference Link.?

Comment: Not really sorry. Finding bends and intersections in your GIS data is a GIS issue, not a NetLogo one. That is, you should be importing these features into NetLogo rather than trying to create them within NetLogo. If you don't know how to do that with whatever GIS software you are using, then you should ask a question about that.